# How to get bounding box for each symbol on number plate

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, object-detection

I want to train some neural network to detect symbols on a car license plate.
I got 10k pictures with plates, and 10k strings, that contains text, represented on plates. For example, this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUcuR.jpg), has name:"В394ТТ64.png"  (others pictures has +- same quality and size, but different shadows\contrast\light and stuff).

So, what do i want to do?

I want to automatically create PASCAL VOC xml files, containing information about each symbol on a plate. Then I want to train neural network to detect symbols and their classes. I already know which symbols appear on picture, but I don't know how to get bounding box coordinates.

I tried to use OpenCV and binary segmentation, but lightning, shadows, size and noise on pictures are too various.

Also, I tried to find trained neural networks, that can detect symbols, or train one by myself, but failed.

So, how can I get bounding box for each symbol on a license plate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another way to solve this problem.

1. I wrote a script, that generates different images with number plates and xml files for each image. I generated 10k images.
2. Then i augmented them so they look more like "real world" images. Now i have 14k images. 4 from original set, and 10k augmented.
3. Trained ssd_mobilenet model.
4. After, i used autoannotation to detect boxes on real images
5. Trained model one more time, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple methods to do this.

Manly, you will have to go over your image and do object detection on each segment of the image.
In Your case that should be more easy as it is already a defined area. Probably move from left to right in strides.

Using an MNIST trained classifier, you can classify the number on the image part. If you get a result with p of e.g., 90% you get the coordinates from that part of the image as your boundingbox coordiantes.

You can of course reuse known architectures such as R-CNN or Yolo

[Here](https://cv-tricks.com/object-detection/faster-r-cnn-yolo-ssd/) you can find a nice overview.

Good luck